# Angularjs (1.2.10) $http.post throws 404 error while posting from phonegap to node.js server (cors request)

Tags: node.js, angularjs, cordova, cors

I am trying to post a comment to a nodejs server but i am getting 404 error. I have used cors module on server side to handles cors request. I am using typescript.

cors module: https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors

```
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
(<any>app).options('*', cors()); // include before other routes
app.use((<any>app).router);
```

Following is my endpoint code

```
app.post("/api/object/addcomment/:id", authenticatebearer(), (req, res) => {
    var id = this.ParseInt(req.params.id);
    var comment: string = req.body.CommentText;
    if (this.IsNullOrUndefined(id) && this.IsNullOrUndefined(comment))
        return this.SendInputError("input is empty.", res);

    (new OM.ObjectManager()).AddComment(req.user.userId, id, comment, (err, commentId) => {
        if (err) return this.SendInternalError(err.message, res);
        return res.json(commentId);
    });
});
```

I am calling above endpoint from angularjs app,

```
myApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
});

function addComment(id, comment, callback) {
    var URL = Client.Config.RestUrl + "api/object/addcomment/" + id.toString() + '?access_token=' + this.RootScope.LogInUser.accessToken;
    this.$http.post(URL, JSON.stringify({ CommentText: comment }))
        .success((commentId, status) => {
            callback(null, commentId);
        })
        .error((data, status) => {
            callback(new Error("An unexpected error occured while adding comment."), null);
        });
}
```

This code is working properly in the desktop environment. Please see the network log from chrome,
[image]

**In phonegap, the function call executes successfully and the comment is added to the system but the $http.post is giving 404 error (gets response in error callback).** Please see the network log from adb debugging tool (this works with android 4.4.2),
[image]

I am struggling for this from last two day. Unable to find a solution. Please help me.
Thanks in advance. Sorry for my english.

Comment: not sure if it applies here but did you try to allow access to your server by configuring access origin in config.xml?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is no problem in the above code. I am using ionic framework for mobile. I used tab view in the above page and added form control as a child to the content directive provided by ionic framework. This was giving a problem. When I moved the form control the problem gets solved.

Comment: I think I had the same problem and figured it out. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/21839620/356016.