# Angular $http.get and jQuery $.getJSON error, but URL opens fine in own tab

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, cors

I'm stumped. I'm trying to make a simple customer lookup request by first name. Both `jQuery.ajax()` (from the console) and Angular's `$http.get()` error out, but I don't know why. When I open in another tab the same URL given to those functions, it displays the expected JSON response.

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax("http://[ip#]:8081/customerservice/customer/search?firstName=John", {
  "dataType": "json",
  "success": function() {
    alert("success");
    console.log("jQuery data", data);
  },
  "error": function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("error");
    console.log("jQuery jqXHR", jqXHR);
    console.log("jQuery textStatus", textStatus);
    console.log("jQuery errorThrown", errorThrown);
  },
  "complete": function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("complete");
    console.log("jQuery jqXHR", jqXHR);
    console.log("jQuery textStatus", textStatus);
  }
});
```

*result*: The error and complete alerts fire. `textStatus` is "error", `errorThrown` is an empty string, jqXHR contains

```
readyState    0
responseText  ""
status        0
statusText    "error"
```

**Angular**

```
return $http.get('http://[ip#]:8081/customerservice/customer/search?firstName=John',
    {
        responseType: "json"
    }
)
.success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    alert("angular success");
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config){
    alert("angular error");
    console.log(status);
    console.log(headers());
    console.log(config);
})
;
```

*result* I see a "200 OK" and response time in Firebug with the given URL. *status* is 404, *headers()* returns an empty object, and the config object is

```
headers           Object { Accept="application/json, text/plain, */*"}
Accept            "application/json, text/plain, */*"
method            "GET"
responseType      "json"
transformRequest  [function()]
    0
    function()
transformResponse [function()]
    0
    function()
url               "http://[ip#]:8081/customerservice/customer/search?firstName=John"
```

Firebug also shows

```
Response Headers
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Sat, 15 Feb 2014 05:13:02 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding   chunked

Request Headers
Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
DNT 1
Host    [ip#]:8081
Origin  http://127.0.0.1
Referer http://127.0.0.1/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
```

*other info* I'm running this in a VM, though I'm still able to access the Internet at large, and [ip#] directly. I'm new to Angular, which is why I tried it with jQuery.

So, what's going on? I built this off the Angular UI Typeahead example, and it worked fine with the Google geocode URL. Is it because I'm using an IP# and/or port? Is it something glaring that I just don't see?

**Update**: The CORS headers have been added, and jQuery now works, but Angular is giving 404s. It seems the sent-by-default `X-Requested-With` header [was a problem with CORS in 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16662590/356016), but I'm using 1.2.

**jQuery**

```
$.post(
    "http://[ip#]:8081/customerservice/customer/search",
    "firstName=John&lastName=Smith",
    function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log("success!", data);
    }
);
```

**Angular**

```
$http.post("http://[ip#]:8081/customerservice/customer/search",
        "firstName=John&lastName=Smith"
    )
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.result = data;
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.result = data || "Request failed";
        console.log("status: ", status);
        console.log("headers: ", headers());
        console.log("config: ", config);
    })
;
```

Comment: looks like a same origin policy violation issue... whether the page and the resource are in the dame domain?

Comment: yep, definitely a CORS issue.  you will need to make changes to your server to the allow-origin and allow-headers settings.  The browsers are preflighting your request, and determining that what your xHr settings are configured to send, vs what the endpoint is configured to receive.

Comment: That's got to be it. If one of you will submit an answer, I'll accept after I can get the server updated to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Arun P Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny) and [Brian Vanderbusch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1106939/brian-vanderbusch) pointed out, it was a CORS issue.

Adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header allowed the jQuery response to start working.

However, "the $http service will automatically add certain HTTP headers to all requests" ["[Setting HTTP Headers](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)", AngularJS docs]. In this case, it was a `Content-Type` header, and it caused another CORS issue: `OPTIONS ... Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`

This did not show up in Firebug nor Firefox's Console. It wasn't until I tried Chrome that I got any output to help debug.

The solution is to:

1. Add `Content-Type` to `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` (see note), or
2. Delete the default `Content-Type` header from the request, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16662590/356016).

   ```
   myApp.config(function($httpProvider){
       delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'];
   });
   ```

Note: My fellow dev had specified `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` of `x-requested-with`, so I don't know if that single entry negates all others, or if `Content-Type` needs to be specified either way.